# How to check if a control was clicked manually?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a `ToggleButton` with this structure:

```
<ToggleButton Focusable="False" Width="19" Height="19" x:Name="tbBtn" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked"/>
```

Now my goal is check in the `ToggleButton_Checked` event if the user has clicked this event manually, or instead I fired this event through code.

In particular, in some situation I set the `IsChecked` property behind code, like this:

```
tbBtn.IsChecked = true;
```

Is possible check in the sender:

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //perform check
}
```

If this event was trigger manually or set behind code? Maybe it's a property in the sender that I don't know about?

Comment: When you `Check` it in your code raise a `bool` flag, and then check that boolean in your event handler?

Comment: Ordinarily, you would have a variable storing the value of the toggle status, and then bind the ToggleButton to this variable. That way, your code would just change the variable, so any call to `ToggleButton_Checked` would be the user. WPF binding is an incredibly important technique to know about if you are using WPF - I strongly encourage you to read up on it in detail.

Comment: @FirstStep I need to execute some method in order, so in my case the variable flag it's not very helpfull. There is no way to get this inside the `sender` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like:

```
ToggleButton button = sender as ToggleButton;
```

else

```
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked)
   {
      // Code for Checked state
   }
   else
   {
      // Code for Un-Checked state
   }
}
```

XAML

```
<ToggleButton Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="485.738,254.419,0,0"     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" IsEnabled="True" Click="ToggleButton_Click">Timeout</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Hi, try it where? Could you please add some description.

Comment: Unchained  if((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked ?? false)

Comment: or If it's two state if((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked.Value) {}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the click event instead.

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name ="tbBtn" Content="Test" Click="ToggleButton_Click"></ToggleButton>
```

Code behind;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbBtn.IsChecked = true; 
    }

    private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as ToggleButton;
        if(tb != null)
        {
            if(tb.IsChecked.HasValue && tb.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("AlreadyChecked");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class level variable to track it. So, code will be something like

```
ClickedFromCode = true;
tbBtn.IsChecked = true;
ClickedFromCode = false;
```

Same variable can be used for multiple events fired from code. Now catch this boolean within the

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //perform check
   if (ClickedFromCode)
   { //do something
   }
   else
   {  //do something
   }
}
```